# Navisworks Treeview to Datatable

Tags: c#, database, datatable, treeview, autodesk-navisworks

I want to covert a treeview from a model in navisworks and create a datatable.
I tried to use foreach but no luck.

any help would be Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by getting the Descendants and passed this into an IEnumerable

```
var Descendants = PL.oDoc.Models.First.RootItem.Descendants.Select(x => x);
```

and then with this method I convert that into an datatable:

```
    public static DataTable DataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var tb = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[props.Length];
            for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }

            tb.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return tb;
    }
```